# Imagem desalinhada CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Ao colocar uma imagem no canto superior direito na minha página, a imagem que fica embaixo no lado esquerdo desalinhou e foi para baixo.

Imagem embaixo antes de colocar as imagens no superior direito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagem depois de colocar imagem no superior direito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HMTL:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="conteudo_ordenar">
            <h3 class="titulo_ordenar">Ordenar Pesquisa</h3>
            <p class="ordena"><span class="caret"></span> Marca</p>
            <p class="ordena"><span class="caret"></span> Tamanho</p>
            <p class="ordena"><span class="caret"></span> Cor</p>
            <p class="ordena"><span class="caret"></span> Faixa De Preço</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9">
        <h3 class="titulo">CAMISETAS</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="linha">
            <img src="imagens/camisa_1.JPG" alt="camisa1" class="imagem_teste" />
            <br />
            <a href="#">
                <p class="descricao_produto">Calça Jeans Armani</p>
                <h4 class="preco"> A partir de R$134,99</h4>
                <button class="saiba_mais" id="saiba_mais1">SAIBA MAIS</button> 
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="linha">
            <img src="imagens/camisa_2.JPG" alt="camisa2" class="imagem_teste" />
            <br />
            <a href="#">
                <p class="descricao_produto">Calça Jeans Armani</p>
                <h4 class="preco"> A partir de R$134,99</h4>
                <button class="saiba_mais" id="saiba_mais1">SAIBA MAIS</button> 
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="linha">
            <img src="imagens/camisa_3.JPG" alt="camisa3" class="imagem_teste" />
            <br />
            <a href="#">
                <p class="descricao_produto">Calça Jeans Armani</p>
                <h4 class="preco"> A partir de R$134,99</h4>
                <button class="saiba_mais" id="saiba_mais1">SAIBA MAIS</button> 
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img src="imagens/shipping.jpg" alt="iamgem embaixo do ordenar" class="imagem_ordena">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.saiba_mais{

background-color: #00008B;
 color: white;
 padding: 16px;
 font-size: 13px;
 border: none;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 20px;

 }

 .linha {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
 height: 390px;
 display: inline-block;
  width: 99%;
 }

.imagem_teste{

 width: 90%;
}

.descricao_produto{
color:black;
 font-weight: 700;
}
 .preco{
  color:red;
 }

.linha a{
display: none;
}


 .linha:hover a{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  }

.linha:hover{
 border-color: #E0E0DA;

 }

.imagem_ordena{
width: 100%;

}

.conteudo_ordenar{

    border:1px solid #E0E0DA;
    border-top: 3px solid #00008B;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #00008B;
    height: 300px;


    overflow: auto; /* isto para evitar o conteúdo transborde o "container", por causa da altura limite de "200px height" definido acima */
}

.titulo_ordenar{
background-color: #00008B;
color:White;
text-align: center;
 margin: 0; /* Aplica um reset à margem automática do título atribuída pelo Navegador */
 height: 50px;


}

.ordena{
outline: 1px solid #E0E0DA;
 padding: 12px;

}
```

Comment: Esta pergunta já não foi feita anteriormente?

Comment: eu apaguei a pergunta anterior pois não tinha colocado parte do codigo

Answer (score 0):

É que sua imagem "shipping" está fora da divisão do menu lateral, tenta colocar ela dentro e criar uma divisão para as imagens da camiseta como conteúdo.
Nesta imagem é uma base de como seria mais ou menos.

[image: Segue um modelo de como seria mais ou menos.]

Answer (score 0):

Pra entender melhor.
Em sua divisão onde está o conteúdo de navegação:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="conteudo_ordenar">
        <h3 class="titulo_ordenar">Ordenar Pesquisa</h3>
        <p class="ordena"><span class="caret"></span> Marca</p>
        <p class="ordena"><span class="caret"></span> Tamanho</p>
        <p class="ordena"><span class="caret"></span> Cor</p>
        <p class="ordena"><span class="caret"></span> Faixa De Preço</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Coloque a imagem shipping dentro dela, pois ela está em última opção em seu Html, assim os conteúdos de imagens de camisetas e talz irá deixa-lá desformatada.

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="conteudo_ordenar">
        <h3 class="titulo_ordenar">Ordenar Pesquisa</h3>
        <p class="ordena"><span class="caret"></span> Marca</p>
        <p class="ordena"><span class="caret"></span> Tamanho</p>
        <p class="ordena"><span class="caret"></span> Cor</p>
        <p class="ordena"><span class="caret"></span> Faixa De Preço</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="imagens/shipping.jpg" alt="iamgem embaixo do ordenar" class="imagem_ordena">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: obrigado por responder Matheus, quando eu coloco do jeito que você postou, a imagem fica ao lado do Ordenar Pesquisa e não embaixo